# JavaScript: почему использование var в console.log() приводит к ошибке?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Почему в консоле возникает ошибка `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var` при использовании выражения:

```
console.log(var check = document.querySelectorAll("#browsers"));
```

А отсутствие `var` возвращает массив данных []:

```
console.log(check = document.querySelectorAll("#browsers"));
```

В чем разница?

Спасибо!

Comment: Ответ простой `var` нельзя использовать в параметрах. Зря минусуют, `console.log('a is %s', (function(){ var a; a= 100; return a; })())`. Консоль Chrome очень мощная штука.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разница в том, что ключевое слово *var* определяет *var statement*, которое используется для инициализации переменных и не может использоваться в качестве параметров.

В отличие от этого, выражение присваивания, вполне может использоваться в качестве параметра функции, даже не смотря на то, что неявно инициализирует глобальную переменную (если она не была объявлена раньше) *check*.